# nav menu styling issues

Tags: html, css, nav

I have been given a psd of a nav menu and im trying to recreate it using css and html.

I have set up a jsfiddle instead of posting my code on here so people can mess about with it.
http://jsfiddle.net/XdefV/
The code in the js fiddle is my attempt, but as you will be able to see its a little bit off.

What im trying to recreate is this:

[image]

Can anyone help me better recreate the image?

Comment: I see it perfect. What change do you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XdefV/5/)** should get you on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

here you go.  Much closer:

http://jsfiddle.net/XdefV/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.
(i'm basing this on your 968px image width)

http://jsfiddle.net/XdefV/6/